# Unregister PhoneStateListener from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I am monitoring phone state through broadcast receiver, and for that I register a PhoneStateListener in onReceive of the receiver. Now if user wants to disable this feature, I disable the broadcast receiver, but the listener keeps running, and i am notified of the phone state. How can I unregister the PhoneStateListener registered in the broadcast receiver?

Answer (score 6):

As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen%28android.telephony.PhoneStateListener,%20int%29) says:

> To unregister a listener, pass the listener object and set the events argument to LISTEN_NONE (0).

For example:

```
    telephonyManager.listen(myListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
```

Comment: I already tried this, it give nullpointer exception. I think this is due to the life of broadcast receiver which creates the listener. So when i unregister it, the broadcast receiver no longer exists. Thus the nullpointer exception

Comment: The lifetime of the `BroadcastReceiver` is short. You'll need to store a reference to `myListener` in a static variable so that it doesn't go away. Make sure that you set the static variable to `null` after you unregister the listener, so that you don't have a memory leak.